# Hibernate column nullness default

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

For a Hibernate table's column definition, if I don't specify not-null or @NotNull, what does the nullability default to?

Example:

```
<class name="Person" table="person">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="long"/>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
</class>
```

Is `name` nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `name` is nullable.

Default behaviour is not nullable for primitive types (`int`, `double`, etc) and nullable otherwise.